# Check radio button if

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select a radio button depending on an input field. This seems very simple but its not working. Basically a user fills out a form and depending on the state input field, it picks the state tax radio button.

The code below is not firing for some reason, any idea's?

The input field

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="state" class="col-sm-3 control-label">State</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" name="state" placeholder="State" onblur="picktax();" required />
  </div>
</div>
```

The radio button

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="emailaddress" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Tax</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <br>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="px" name="tax2" id="radio1" class="radio" value="0" / />
            <span class="lbl">Tax Exempt</span>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="px" name="tax2" id="radio2" class="radio" value="0.0875" />
            <span class="lbl">NYC 8.875%</span>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="px" name="tax2" id="radio3" class="radio" value="0.08625" />
            <span class="lbl">LI 8.625%</span>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="px" name="tax2" id="radio4" class="radio" value="0.07" />
            <span class="lbl">NJ 7%</span>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="px" name="tax2" id="radio5" class="radio" value="0.06" />
            <span class="lbl">Philly 6%</span>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="px" name="tax2" id="radio6" class="radio" value="0.0635" />
            <span class="lbl">CT 6.35%</span>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script

```
<script>
function picktax() {

var statevalue = document.getElementById('state').value;
var nyvalue = "NY";
var livalue = "LI";
var njvalue = "NJ";

if (statevalue == nyvalue) {

$("#radio2").prop("checked", true)

} elseif (statevalue == livalue) {

$("#radio3").prop("checked", true)

} elseif (statevalue == njvalue) {

$("#radio4").prop("checked", true)


} else {

 alert("test");
}

}
</script>
```

updated, still not firing

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` and `===` are for comparison.

Comment: Also there's no `elseif` keyword in JavaScript. Keep your developer console open so that you see errors reported by the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example shows that you are new to JavaScript so whilst I wouldn't code it quite like this myself here's your code corrected enough to work.

As mentioned in the comments there is no `elseif` keyword in JS and you must use double or triple equals operator for evaluating.

Nethertheless, you were getting close to something workable.

```js
function picktax() {

var statevalue = document.getElementById('state').value;
var nyvalue = "NY";
var livalue = "LI";
var njvalue = "NJ";

if (statevalue == nyvalue) {

$("#radio2").prop("checked", true)

} else if (statevalue == livalue) {

$("#radio3").prop("checked", true)

} else if (statevalue == njvalue) {

$("#radio4").prop("checked", true)

} else {

 alert("test");
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="state" class="col-sm-3 control-label">State</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" name="state" placeholder="State" oninput="picktax();" required />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="emailaddress" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Tax</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <br>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="px" name="tax2" id="radio1" class="radio" value="0" / />
            <span class="lbl">Tax Exempt</span>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="px" name="tax2" id="radio2" class="radio" value="0.0875" />
            <span class="lbl">NYC 8.875%</span>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="px" name="tax2" id="radio3" class="radio" value="0.08625" />
            <span class="lbl">LI 8.625%</span>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="px" name="tax2" id="radio4" class="radio" value="0.07" />
            <span class="lbl">NJ 7%</span>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="px" name="tax2" id="radio5" class="radio" value="0.06" />
            <span class="lbl">Philly 6%</span>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="px" name="tax2" id="radio6" class="radio" value="0.0635" />
            <span class="lbl">CT 6.35%</span>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the comments, your code has some syntax errors. Also, there are a few ways you could improve it, for example I use a `switch` instead of `if`. Nothing wrong with `if`, I'm just providing an example. Fixed code would be:

```
function picktax() {

    var statevalue = $('#state').val();
    var radio = $();

    switch (statevalue) {
        case "NY":
            radio = $("#radio2");
            break;
        case "LI":
            radio = $("#radio3");
            break;
        case "NJ":
            radio = $("#radio4");
            break;
        default:
            alert("test");
            break;
    }

    radio.prop("checked", true);
}
```